# How to reduce the width of choice column in List in SP 2013

Tags: list, css

I have a list with 6 columns from which 2 are choice columns.I want to reduce the width of those columns.
I tried applying the below css to choice column but it didn't had any effect.

```
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='<ColumnName>']
{
  width:250px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Launch SharePoint Designer 2010, open the View folder in the directory tree on the left side of the window, then double-click the file labeled "AllItems.aspx".

**Step 2:**
Go to the "Design" tab at the bottom of the window, click on the right edge of the column you want to adjust, then drag it to the left or right to resize it.

**Step 3:**
Switch to the "Code" tab at the bottom of the window.

**Step 4:**
Find the line that includes the following: `<th scope="col"` Remove this code from the line: `Nowrap=’Nowrap’` Replace it with the following code: `style="width: ##px; overflow: auto; white-space: normal;"` Substitute "##" with the number of pixels you want to use for the column width.

**Step 5:**
Scroll down to the line that includes `<td style` and add the following code: `style="width: ##px; overflow: auto; white-space: normal;"` Replace "##" with the number of pixels you want to use for the column width.

**Step 6:**
Click on the "Save" button in the top toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mention works just fine. Just add it to a script editor web part to the page where you display the list and paste the code.

```
<style type='text/css'>
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='ChoiceColumnDisplayName']
{
  width:250px;
}
</style>
```